# Disabling weak ciphers on OpenShift router

Tags: ssl, yaml, openshift, tls1.2

I'm trying to disabling CBC ciphers on an Openshift Router (v 3.11) by editing the yaml file, but i can't find out how to setup the ROUTER_CIPHERS (want to set the value to modern) environment variable on the router level.

Any tips on the yaml structure to achieve this? Where sould the env variables be placed?

Some doc that i've already checked:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html#bind-ciphers

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#ciphers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `oc set env` command so set an environment variable in your Router DeploymentConfig (named "router" in my case):

```
oc set env dc/router ROUTER_CIPHERS=intermediate
```

or

```
oc set env dc/router ROUTER_CIPHERS=modern
```

The available profiles come from your [second link](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#ciphers). This will result in the environment variable being added to the `spec.container.env` field for the Router container.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've already tried to set the env variable with oc tool but i get the following error:  
  
`oc env dc/router-name ROUTER_CIPHERS=modern
Error from server (NotFound): deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io "router-name" not found`  
  
 I don't know why because i can see the router on the console. Is there any workaround to reference the router?

Comment: You are probably executing the command in the wrong namespace or with the wrong router name. Check if you can see the DeploymentConfig with `oc get dc` or change the namespace with `oc project default` to the correct namespace.